# map filter in Array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

Need help for filtering an array.

```
let array = [pair: "TZS_SFDT", pair: "TZFD_TG", pair: "G_TDDD"]
```

How could I separate the groups of letters in two objects like:

```
arraySeperated1 = [part1: "TZS", part1:"TZFD", part1: "G"]
arraySeperated2 = [part2: "SFDT", part2: "TG", part2: "TDDD"]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Those all are `Dictionaries` **not the Array.**

Comment: In Swift, [:] syntax is for Dictionary and Dictionaries can only have unique keys. So `pair:` can't be declared twice or more. Same for `part1:`, it can't be returned multiple times.

Comment: So, i need help in filtering a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make it easier. My Array looks like this:

Comment: array = [[pair: String, description: String, Value: Int]]

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't post code in comments. Please also take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Thanks.

Comment: now i want to filter the "pair"-value through a public struct.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do with your illegal code (*fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys*) is to instead see/interpret it as Array of String:

```
let array = ["TZS_SFDT", "TZFD_TG", "G_TDDD"]
```

Then to split it:

```
let arraySeparated1 = array.map { $0.substring(to: $0.range(of: "_")!.lowerBound) }
let arraySeparated2 = array.map { $0.substring(from: $0.range(of: "_")!.upperBound) }
```

---

OK, after clarification from comment, you actually got:

```
let array = [[pair: "TZS_SFDT", description: "", Value: 0],
             [pair: "TZFD_TG", description: "", Value: 0],
             [pair: "G_TDDD", description: "", Value: 0]]
```

So you split as:

```
let arraySeparated1 = array.map { ["part1":$0.pair.substring(to: $0.pair.range(of: "_")!.lowerBound)] }
let arraySeparated2 = array.map { ["part2":$0.pair.substring(from: $0.pair.range(of: "_")!.upperBound)] }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for. 
The last remaining problem is, that pair-values still includes the quotes. Like pair: "\"TZS_SFDT\"".
 Is there a way to "eliminate the quotes additionally?

Comment: I know, it´s a problem of my source. But it would be great to solve this in this procedure as well.

Comment: Cœur: Why is it illegal?  Andy: your original question has been answered. Why not accept this and ask a new question about cropping your string.

Comment: @Mozahler I've added the reason why original code is illegal in Swift: _fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys_